# Getting errror when trying to run Monotouch-bindngs sample facebook

Tags: c#, facebook, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I am getting following error.....

Error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log. (MT5202).

Compiling to native code
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch -sdkroot "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer" -v --cache "/Users/ravichandra/Downloads/monotouch-bindings-master/facebook/sample/obj/Debug/mtouch-cache" --nomanifest --nosign -sim "/Users/ravichandra/Downloads/monotouch-bindings-master/facebook/sample/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/sample.app" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll" -r "/Users/ravichandra/Downloads/monotouch-bindings-master/ATMHud/sample/MonoTouch.Dialog.dll" -r "/Users/ravichandra/Downloads/monotouch-bindings-master/facebook/binding/Facebook.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Json.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Web.Services.dll" -debug -profiling -nolink -sdk "6.0" "/Users/ravichandra/Downloads/monotouch-bindings-master/facebook/sample/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/sample.exe"
MonoTouch version 6.0.0 using framework: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk
Copied /Users/ravichandra/Downloads/monotouch-bindings-master/facebook/sample/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/sample.exe to /Users/ravichandra/Downloads/monotouch-bindings-master/facebook/sample/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/sample.app/sample.exe
Copied /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll to /Users/ravichandra/Downloads/monotouch-bindings-master/facebook/sample/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/sample.app/monotouch.dll
Copied /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/mscorlib.dll to /Users/ravichandra/Downloads/monotouch-bindings-master/facebook/sample/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/sample.app/mscorlib.dll
Copied /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll to /Users/ravichandra/Downloads/monotouch-bindings-master/facebook/sample/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/sample.app/System.Core.dll
Copied /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll to /Users/ravichandra/Downloads/monotouch-bindings-master/facebook/sample/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/sample.app/System.dll
Copied /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/Mono.Security.dll to /Users/ravichandra/Downloads/monotouch-bindings-master/facebook/sample/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/sample.app/Mono.Security.dll
Copied /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.dll to /Users/ravichandra/Downloads/monotouch-bindings-master/facebook/sample/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/sample.app/System.Xml.dll
Copied /var/folders/w9/w_xlv4x54j97t8kpzlq2531h0000gn/T/tmp658e855c.tmp/Facebook.dll to /Users/ravichandra/Downloads/monotouch-bindings-master/facebook/sample/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/sample.app/Facebook.dll
Copied /Users/ravichandra/Downloads/monotouch-bindings-master/ATMHud/sample/MonoTouch.Dialog.dll to /Users/ravichandra/Downloads/monotouch-bindings-master/facebook/sample/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/sample.app/MonoTouch.Dialog.dll
Copied /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Web.Services.dll to /Users/ravichandra/Downloads/monotouch-bindings-master/facebook/sample/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/sample.app/System.Web.Services.dll
Copied /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Json.dll to /Users/ravichandra/Downloads/monotouch-bindings-master/facebook/sample/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/sample.app/System.Json.dll
Generated /var/folders/w9/w_xlv4x54j97t8kpzlq2531h0000gn/T/tmp658e855c.tmp/main.m
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -arch i386 -gdwarf-2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -fobjc-abi-version=2 -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -arch i386  -std=c99 -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk -c /var/folders/w9/w_xlv4x54j97t8kpzlq2531h0000gn/T/tmp658e855c.tmp/main.m -o /var/folders/w9/w_xlv4x54j97t8kpzlq2531h0000gn/T/tmp658e855c.tmp/main.x86.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc  -Wl,-no_pie -arch i386 -gdwarf-2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -fobjc-abi-version=2 -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk  /var/folders/w9/w_xlv4x54j97t8kpzlq2531h0000gn/T/tmp658e855c.tmp/main.x86.o -o /var/folders/w9/w_xlv4x54j97t8kpzlq2531h0000gn/T/tmp658e855c.tmp/sample -framework CFNetwork -framework Foundation -framework GameKit -framework MapKit -framework MediaPlayer -framework MessageUI -framework OpenGLES -framework StoreKit -framework UIKit -framework AddressBookUI -framework SystemConfiguration -framework AddressBook -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework CoreData -framework ExternalAccessory -framework Accounts -framework Social -weak_framework AssetsLibrary -weak_framework CoreBluetooth -weak_framework CoreTelephony -weak_framework EventKit -weak_framework EventKitUI -weak_framework CoreMotion -weak_framework GLKit -weak_framework iAd -weak_framework MediaToolbox -weak_framework NewsstandKit -weak_framework Twitter -weak_framework PassKit -weak_framework CoreImage -weak_framework CoreText -weak_framework ImageIO -weak_framework CoreMedia -weak_framework CoreMIDI -weak_framework CoreVideo -weak_framework AdSupport -weak_framework QuickLook -lz -u _mono_pmip -u _CreateZStream -u _CloseZStream -u _Flush -u _ReadZStream -u _WriteZStream -liconv -lmono-2.0 -lmonotouch -L/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/usr/lib -u _catch_exception_raise  -force_load /var/folders/w9/w_xlv4x54j97t8kpzlq2531h0000gn/T/tmp658e855c.tmp/libFacebookSDK.a -ObjC -lsqlite3
Process exited with code 1, command:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc  -Wl,-no_pie -arch i386 -gdwarf-2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -fobjc-abi-version=2 -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk  /var/folders/w9/w_xlv4x54j97t8kpzlq2531h0000gn/T/tmp658e855c.tmp/main.x86.o -o /var/folders/w9/w_xlv4x54j97t8kpzlq2531h0000gn/T/tmp658e855c.tmp/sample -framework CFNetwork -framework Foundation -framework GameKit -framework MapKit -framework MediaPlayer -framework MessageUI -framework OpenGLES -framework StoreKit -framework UIKit -framework AddressBookUI -framework SystemConfiguration -framework AddressBook -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework CoreData -framework ExternalAccessory -framework Accounts -framework Social -weak_framework AssetsLibrary -weak_framework CoreBluetooth -weak_framework CoreTelephony -weak_framework EventKit -weak_framework EventKitUI -weak_framework CoreMotion -weak_framework GLKit -weak_framework iAd -weak_framework MediaToolbox -weak_framework NewsstandKit -weak_framework Twitter -weak_framework PassKit -weak_framework CoreImage -weak_framework CoreText -weak_framework ImageIO -weak_framework CoreMedia -weak_framework CoreMIDI -weak_framework CoreVideo -weak_framework AdSupport -weak_framework QuickLook -lz -u _mono_pmip -u _CreateZStream -u _CloseZStream -u _Flush -u _ReadZStream -u _WriteZStream -liconv -lmono-2.0 -lmonotouch -L/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/usr/lib -u _catch_exception_raise  -force_load /var/folders/w9/w_xlv4x54j97t8kpzlq2531h0000gn/T/tmp658e855c.tmp/libFacebookSDK.a -ObjC -lsqlite3
ld: framework not found AdSupport
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ld: framework not found AdSupport collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

You need a newer Xcode version (any stable version of 4.5 - not a Developer Preview), the one you have doesn't include the AdSupport framework.

Comment: yes you are right just now i knew the solution from bugzilla.

Comment: hey you Rolf just now you solved my question in Bugzilla...Here also

Comment: @DorababuDodda: this way the answer is here too, so that people who come here from Google will know the answer too.

Comment: I'm using xcode 4.6 but still getting the same error. 
Also tried with 4.5.2 but still same problem.

Comment: @user958880: I don't think your case is identical. Please open a new question with information for your build error.

Answer (score 2):

> Error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log. (MT5202).

MonoTouch is telling you that the native linker was unhappy. Details are available in the build logs (you can see it from MonoDevelop's Error List pad, click on the **Build Output** button).

Sadly not posting the build log does not help much. Can you edit your question and add the few error/warnings lines of the output before the MT5202 ?

A quick guess is that the bindings were made with ARMv6 **only** binaries and Xcode 4.5 (and later) will **only** allow you to produce ARMv7 (and ARMv7s) binaries. Fixing this would require newer bindings (compiled with binaries for ARMv7) or using Xcode 4.4 / iOS5.1 SDK which allows building ARMv6 binaries.

Comment: can you please now check my question...I edited with the build error.